# Get different Thumbnail of video in windows 8 C# application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, video-thumbnails

How can we get thumbnail of video file in windows 8 C#/xaml application? Here is simple method available for getting first frame of video

```
file.GetThumbnailAsync()
```

But I want to get different frames of video as thumbnail. I want to get 4 5 different thumbnail of video at desires time of video stream?